# git checkout <file> leaves it in "modified" state?

Tags: git

I ran

```
  git checkout js/cider_utils.js
```

And the result is

```
$ git status
On branch frontend
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   js/cider_utils.js
```

I am trying to revert the cached changes - and had thought that would have done the trick. So then what is the correct way?

Note: I subsequently did  the following - which is incorrect:

```
git rm --cached js/cider_utils.js
```

That results in the file being staged for *deletion*

```
$ git status

deleted:    js/cider_utils.js
```

But we do not want to remove it from git - only to revert the staged changes. So what should be done differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to revert the cached changes

Then you should not have said simple `checkout`, which keeps the cached changes, and changes the work tree to match them. You did exactly the opposite of what you wanted.

Git has already told you the right answer:

```
(use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  modified:   js/cider_utils.js
```

You should have said

```
git restore --staged js/cider_utils.js
```

That means: Make the version of this file in the index (cache) look like the version in the most recent commit.

---

**NOTE:** `restore` and `switch` were introduced in Git 2.23, in mid-2019, exactly in order to relieve `checkout` of its confusing overloading. But `restore` also picks up some `reset` functionality. An earlier version of Git would indeed have advised use of `reset`, as in the answer given by [StephenBoesch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65039083/341994):

```
 use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage
```

I was merely trying to keep my response consonant with what Git was *already telling* the OP. The point is, the answer is right there in what Git is saying. I find that users tend to ignore messages from Git, when it is very often being remarkably helpful if only one will listen.

Comment: Never noticed `restore` before.

Comment: @StephenBoesch It's true it's relatively recent. `restore` and `switch` were introduced in Git 2.23, in mid-2019, exactly in order to relieve `checkout` of its overloading. But it also picks up some `reset` functionality. An earlier version of Git would indeed have advised use of `reset`, as in your answer. But the OP's version of Git does have `restore`, as is proved by the message from Git itself, so I was just pointing out what was right in front of the OP's eyes. I will add this info to my answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Ah right - the thing to do here is `git reset`

```
$git reset HEAD -- js/cider_utils.js
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   js/cider_utils.js
```

From a comment by @RomainValeri: since `HEAD` is implied a shorter version is

```
$git reset -- js/cider_utils.js
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   js/cider_utils.js
```

Comment: `HEAD` is unneeded here as it's implied in absence of any refspec. `git reset -- js/cider_utils.js`

Comment: Thx @RomainValeri for that shortcut